# Не получается программно закрыть приложение

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `activity`, в который я отправляю, если у клиента проблемы с соединением. Выглядит он так

```
package com.gobonus.gobonus;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class InternetDisabled extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_internet_disabled);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);

        builder.setTitle(R.string.title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.err_503);

        builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
}
```

Отправляю так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, InternetDisabled.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Но почему то идет переход на прошлое Activity. Как полностью закрыть приложение и чтобы оно не отображалось в списке недавних (второе необязательно). Так же пробовал `System.exit(0)`, тогда приложение просто перезапускается. Знаю метод `finishActivity`, но как его использовать - не понимаю. Никаких исключений в консоли нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, нужно было в обоих <strike>контроллерах</strike> классах прописать `finish()`.

Comment: в каких классах?